# Google Sheets ImportHTML can't find table?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-chrome-console

I've used ImportHTML plenty of times before and never really had any issues with it, but for some reason, I can't seem to pull a particular table from Basketball-Reference, even though I've pulled other tables from there just fine. The table I want is the Miscellaneous Stats table lower down on [this page](https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019.html). I've tried every index from 1 to 30 in the function, but none of them past 7 bring in any data. The function I'm using is below, with the 1 changing to whatever index I'm trying:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019.html", "table", 1)
```

I tried using the following code in Chrome's console to find the index of the page, but it didn't return anything:

```
var i = 1; [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("table"), function(x) { console.log(i++, x); });
```

Does anyone know how I can get this table working with ImportHTML?

Answer (score 1):

Well, player0 was correct about being unable to scrape the JS table, but luckily I was able to use the [URL for the embed version of that table](https://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=bbr&url=%2Fleagues%2FNBA_2019.html&div=div_misc_stats), which works perfectly with ImportHTML.

Comment: The URL no longer returns a table, instead is shows "Sports Reference has turned off our widgets service effective January 1, 2023"